# Keep docker-compose container running after ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker

Originally the final line of my `Dockerfile` read:

```
RUN puppet apply /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/master.pp
```

I need the command to run only once the container is created and mounted, so I changed to:

```
ENTRYPOINT puppet apply /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/master.pp
```

The change fixes my original issue but creates another, the container stops after the command finishes.

I found I can keep the container running by by adding something like `&& while true; do sleep 1000; done`.

This seems a little hacky and I'm wondering if there is a better way to keep my container from stopping?

*Note: I've seen some suggestions online where people use flags when running the docker command. So I will point out that I'm initializing this container using `docker-compose`.*

Answer (score 1):

I use `&& sleep infinity`. (Be aware that `busybox sleep` does not provide `infinity` - only the `coreutils` do.)

Comment: Thanks good to know and appreciate the detail on busybox. I will leave this open for now as I'm still looking for another solution. I guess ENTRYPOINT is normally for when you want to use a container as an executable. In my case I just want to run a command when the container is initialized. Reason being I'm running a command using a sensitive key file which isn't present before initializing the container (because it is in an attached volume).